# Перевод обновлённых статей Справки

Tags: обсуждение, локализация, справка

Недавно я обновила две статьи Справки по всей сети. Статьи на русском сайте еще не переведены.

Вот эти две статьи:

1. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer
2. https://stackoverflow.com/help/serial-voting-reversed

Много текста было изменено, но содержание не сильно поменялось. Я воспользовалась возможностью, чтобы обновить эти статьи и сделать их более удобными для чтения и понимания. Если вы хотите, чтобы я обновила их на Stack Overflow на русском, пожалуйста, ответьте копией, которую вы хотели бы, чтобы я использовала. Если есть другие изменения, которые вы хотели бы внести в эти страницы, пожалуйста, не стесняйтесь включать их в предлагаемую вами копию.

---

I recently updated two Help Center articles network-wide. The Russian site's articles are not translated yet.

The two articles are:

1. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer
2. https://stackoverflow.com/help/serial-voting-reversed

A lot of the text has changed, but the contents haven't changed much. I took the opportunity to update these articles and make them easier to read and understand. If you would like me to update these on Russian Stack Overflow, please answer with the copy you would like me to use. If there are other changes you'd like to make to these pages, please feel free to include them in your proposed copy.

(Please feel free to translate this post as well, if you think it would help!)